# Why am I getting a NOT NULL constraint failed when submitting my django form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to add comments to my post model in django but when I try to submit a form it throws a NOT NULL constraint failed error because it cannot find a post even though it is being assigned in the view when saving the form.

here are my models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField('Title', max_length=300)
    slug = models.SlugField('Link')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Creation date', auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='blog_posts')
    content = models.TextField('Content', max_length=2000, default='!')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comment_author')
    body = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Comment {} by {}'.format(self.body, self.user)
```

then this is my form:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ['user', 'body']
```

if I add the 'post' field to fields it displays it as a dropdown and adds the comment to the correct post even if the dropdown option points it to a different one but I don't want it to display the 'post' field in the form at all

and this is the view:

```
def post_detail(request, slug):
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    comments = post.comments.all()
    new_comment = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            new_comment = comment_form.save()
            new_comment.post = post <- this part is being left out for some reason
            new_comment.save()
    else:
        comment_form = CommentForm()

    return render(request, template_name, {'post': post,
                                           'comments': comments,
                                           'new_comment': new_comment,
                                           'comment_form': comment_form})
```

I display the form in the generic way:

```
<form method="post">
    {{ comment_form.as_p }}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

This is the error message: `NOT NULL constraint failed: blog_backend_comment.post_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view function, you are saving comment form before assigning a post

so try this way

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    comment_form = CommentForm(data=request.POST)
    if comment_form.is_valid():
        new_comment = comment_form.save(commit=False) # saves the form but do not save the record to the database
        new_comment.post = post
        new_comment.save() # Now it saves records to the database
```